# Given f: GXH--G f(x, y) = x and h: GXH--H h(x, y) = y show f and h are homomorphism of the group's GXH, G, and H.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

So I want to say f((x, y)(x', y')) = xx'.

Is it safe to assume (a, b)(c, d) = (ac, bd)? The book I using often doesn't state what the operations are. Can I assume the operation is the same for all groups or the Gs and Hs?

So f((a, b)(c, d)) = ac, 
f(a, b)f(c, d) = ac.

And thus f((a, b)(c, d)) = f(a,b)f(c,d).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $(a,b) (c,d) = (ac, bd)$. To justify this, refer back to the [definition of the direct product of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Definition).